# Grabbing Textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<script type="text/javascript">
function Incrementer()
{
    debugger;
    var txtBox = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_TextBox1').value;

   alert(txtBox);
}

</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Up"  OnClientClick="Incrementer();"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Down" runat="server"/>
    </asp:Content>
```

I am unable to capture the textbox in JavaScript. What is the problem?

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?  It works just fine for me.  Double quotes and single quotes don't matter either.  Check to make sure the id matches a unique element on the page.  In other words, don't reuse the same id, and make sure one matches what you put in the quotes.

Comment: when i go in debug mode...it says at the line object required.

Comment: Please paste the HTML that has that ID on it.

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - Where is your element with this id?  ctl00_MainContent_TextBox1?  Don't you need a DIV or something that matches that value, or am I just missing something?  Do you see an element with that ID in your browser source?

Comment: Oops....Jmort, thx....i was using wrong ID!!!!...Its resolved.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re tagged this ASP.net as well because it's quite specific to this problem.

When an ASP.net textbox control is rendered on a page it is assigned a dynamic ID that can change.  There is a property for controls, `ClientID` that provides you with the controls assigned ID so you can use it in your scripts.

Use as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Incrementer()
{
    debugger;
    var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;

   alert(txtBox);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
 alert(txtBox);
```